# Cross database many to many relationships in Laravel with Sqlite

Tags: laravel, sqlite, eloquent

In Laravel Framework 8.20.1 I have two models, User and Item, in two different SQLITE databases, with a many to many relationship.

The intermediate table, called item_user, in the same database as model Item.

I've setup the belongsToMany relatinoship like this in model Item

```
class Item extends Model
{
    ...
    
    protected $connection = 'connection2-name';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    // I have done several tryouts
    //  OR  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'item_user', 'user_id', 'item_id');
    //  OR  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'sqlite-db2.item_user', 'user_id', 'item_id');
    //  OR  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, '/path/to/sqlite-db2.item_user', 'user_id', 'item_id');
    //  OR  return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'connection2-name.item_user', 'user_id', 'item_id');
    }
}
```

When I try to access Item with Users:

```
$item = Item::find($id)->with('users')->get();
```

I get an error that my intermediate table "item_user" doesn't exist.

> General error: 1 no such table: item_user

As far as I have found in my search of the solution, the problem should be that Laravel assumes the intermediate table to exist in the same database as the target relation, so they suggest to add the db name in the belongsToMany, but even that did not solve my issue.

Do you have any hint to come out of this problem?

Comment: At the moment the only solution I can find is to move the table of model Item and item_user intermediate table inside the db where model User is. :(

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create a table `item_users` with fields `user_id and item_id`

Then use relation:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'item_users');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Ilkhomjon, this is what I have done. The problem is not there.
By the way, if you let it singular "item_user" you don't have to specify it in the belongToMany statement.